# Converting user input into nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to get the coordinates for 2 different line segments from the input prompt so that I can calculate their slopes. Is there any way I could get the user's input in the form of `z = [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2]]` and still be able to reference the index of the individual numbers for calculation?

Comment: How does the user provide the input? At the prompt, or via a file?

Answer (score 3):

```
def userInput(x1,y1,x2,y2):
  coord1 = [x1, y1]
  coord2 = [x2, y2]
  return [coord1, coord2]

z = userInput(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(z)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the user to input a valid list or tuple you can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). For example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

z = input("Input pair of coordinates:") # user inputs "[[1, 2],[3, 4]]"
z = literal_eval(z)

print(z[0]) # [1, 2]
print(z[1]) # [3, 4]
```

You will want to validate that the user gave you want you needed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, least efficient way would be to have 4 input calls:

```
x1 = input('First x: ')
y1 = input('First y: ')
x2...
y2...
```

Then cast them all to ints. A more ideal solution would be to take in the whole input and force them to format it, say, 'x, y, x2, y2'.

You could then do:

```
resp = answer.split(', ')
return [resp[:2], resp[2:]]
```